# UIStoryboard calling issues for diffrent device size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, presentviewcontroller

I want to call UIStoryboard for three diffrent device (iphone4s,iphone5 and ipad). I have newly added for iphone4s device. I have the following Storyboard

1. Main_iPhone
2. Main_iPhone4(newly added)
3. Main_iPad

Please check my current  source. Its working working with iphone5.

```
AVCamViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard
storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:NULL]
                                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootController"];

         vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
         vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
         [self.viewControllerCam presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need to change like below and i was run with iphone4s device. but still im seeing "Main_iPhone" storyboard. PLease help me how to switch   Main_iPhone4 when i was run in iphone4s device.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
   CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

   if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
   {   
     storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
   }

   if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
   { 
     storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   }

} 
else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
  storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

AVCamViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];      
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.viewControllerCam presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine and it should work according to that.

But this is not the right way to manage separate storyboard for iPhone 4s & iPhone 5/5s. Instead you can manage using single storyboard for both and arrange the layout using auto-layout, I'm sure it will reduce your lot of work.